# Include script not working when the powershell script is invoked from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a power shell script which has include script in it as below.

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\CheckPermissions.ps1"
```

When the script is invoked from c#, I am getting this error

> **{The term '\CheckPermissions.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.}**

The script works fine when run from PS window.

Is not $PSScriptRoot variable available when script is run from c#?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following to get the script directory:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Note that the folder path returned will end with a backslash (`\`).

Comment: Is not working for me. Actually $PSScriptRoot this works when the script is run directly from PS window and only it is not working when the script is called from c#.

Comment: What version of `PowerShell` is your C# script running? As `$PSScriptRoot` only works in later versions of PowerShell, you can check by outputting the host info to a text file e.g. `host > "C:\HostInfo.txt"`

Comment: This works perfectly when run from powershell window. So version is not a problem. My version of PS is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$scriptpath = "your second file path"
$psContent = @(Get-Content $scriptPath)
[string]$psCmd = $psContent -join "`n"
$secondscriptoutput = iex $psCmd
$secondscriptoutput #output returned by second file
```

Myinvocation will not work when ps scripts are invoked from c# code. Please mark this as answer if it works for you. Thanks!